# How can I get Sum for customer in current month django views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am working on Django project where I want to get total (sum) deposit for each customer in the current month of the year in a list. I am not able to figure it out yet since there is no ID in use in the function request in order to use the .get() method to filter by the customer id.
Below are my Model and views Code:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    othernames = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

#Get the url path of the view
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('customer_create', args=[self.id])

#Making Sure Django Display the name of our Models as it is without Pluralizing
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Customer'

#
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.surname} {self.othernames} - {self.account_number}'

class Deposit(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    acct = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    deposit_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('create_account', args=[self.id])

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.customer} Deposited {self.deposit_amount} by {self.staff.username}'
```

Views Code:

```
def create_account(request):
    current_date = datetime.now().date()
    customers = Customer.objects.all()
    act = customers.account_number
    deposited_this_month = Deposit.objects.filter(customer__account_number=act, date__year=current_date.year, date__month=current_date.month).aggregate(deposited_this_month=Sum('deposit_amount')).get('deposited_this_month') or 0
```

I am having error which says **'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'account_number'**. A better solution for this issue shall be much appreciated.
Please understand that every module import, context and template rendering is taken care of without problems.

Comment: Why not use `Deposit.objects.filter(customer__in=customers, ...` instead? That would remove the need to get every customer's account number. Or, just stop filtering by customer, since you want to get every customer.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Sum of Deposit for each Customer for the given moth and year, you should do:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear, ExtractMonth
from django.db.models import Sum


Deposit.objects.filter(
    date__year=current_date.year,
    date__month=current_date.month
).annotate(
    month= ExtractMonth('date'),
    year= ExtractYear('date'),
).values(
    'customer__account_number',
    'year',
    'month',
).annotate(
    total_deposit=Sum('deposit_amount')
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Eduardo, your solution is good but I have some bugs in it that ***'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'year'*** Thanks

Comment: @apollos could you check if this error is comming from evaluating `current_date.year`. Please share the error trace if not.

Comment: Yes it is evaluating current_date.year

Comment: Try using a hardcode value to see if the query does what you need, and later look for an alternative for your  current_date.year .

Comment: this is my current_date = datetime.now(). How do you get your current date

Comment: I'm not sure way you are seeing this error. Try using, `from django.utils import timezone`, `timezone.now().date().year`